# return retval() if retval() -- is there a way to write that in Ruby without the retval function being called twice?

Tags: ruby, idioms

Suppose I have this code

```
def retval
  # some resource intensive computation
  return whatever
end

def foo
  ...
  return retval if retval
  ...
end
```

Is there a way to restructure that so retval isn't called twice, without doing

```
def foo
  ...
  x = retval
  return x if x
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another variation of the same thing

```
def foo
  if x = retval
    return x
  end
  ...
end
```

I'm afraid you won't get drastically different results if you're looking only on syntax. And besides, what's wrong with this?

```
def foo
  ...
  x = retval
  return x if x
  ...
end
```

This is how I'd write it.

Comment: "what's wrong with this?" ... I think it's not so bad ... I'm just getting spoiled by syntax sugar like `||=` so I wonder if there's something nice to cover this situation.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the two-liner is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can memoize the result in `retval`:

```
def retval
  return @retval if @retval
  # some resource intensive computation

  @retval = whatever
end

def foo
  ...
  return retval if retval
  ...
end
```

For shorter methods, a nice idiom is:

```
def retval
  @somevar ||= some_work
end
```

Comment: Nice, memoization is a great suggestion that I hadn't thought of, though in my case `retval` will return different results under different circumstances, so I can't just do this kind of result caching.  I.e., the next time control passes through `foo` I'll need to re-evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a one-liner

```
return x if (x = retval)
```

will only work if `x` is already defined.

```
if x = retval; x; end
```

*does* work but no one really writes Ruby that way.

Depending on your situation, might

```
return true if retval
```

be possible, or do you actually required that the value returned from `retval` be returned?

**UPDATE**: As the OP says yes the value needs to be returned, Sergio's answer is IMHO correct.  Of course, there is another way to make a one-liner with the rather ugly assignment inside expression:

```
x = retval and return x
```

Yikes! :-)

Comment: You surely meant `if x = retval; x; end`, didn't you? :)

Comment: Yeah, I actually need retval returned.

Comment: Then IMHO Sergio is correct.  In fact I would argue that `x = retval; return x if x` **is** the clearest way.  It says exactly what it means, as clear as can be.  It says "call this method and call its value x.  Now return x if x is truthy".  This is what you want and this is what you should say.  Going for a one liner in this case, would, well, IMHO, obfuscate.  Good question, though; it's fun to consider such things, even if it is not always prudent.  Oh, and speaking of obfuscating: I really would try to stay away from assignment inside of expressions. :)

Comment: Yes, I totally agree that assignment inside expressions is a bad code smell.  So it seems there is no cute Ruby idiom for this situation, and the best solution is `x = retval` followed by `return x if x` as mentioned by Sergio.

Comment: Agreed, though I did update my answer with one more bit of silliness, using the idiomatic and-operator:  `x = retval and return x` :)  It works because `and` is short circuit.